# How to avoid accessing vue instance in multiple JavaScript files?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Preface - while there was a post about an issue similar to this, the recommended solutions involved attaching the vue instance to the window in order to access it in multiple javascript files, which seemed like bad design.

I have the following highly simplified basic structure in my application:

```js
vm = new Vue({
    el:"#vue-app",
    data: {
        messages: [],
        complexTaskInProgress: false
    },
    methods: {
        buttonClicked: function() {
            complexTaskInProgress = true 
            //A method imported from another file 
            await complexTask()
            complexTaskInProgress = false 
        }
    }
})
```

The problem is `complexTask` needs to continuously add values to the `messages` list.

For example - `complexTask` may take 20 seconds to execute and add a value to `messages` every 2 seconds. I can't just wait 20 seconds for `complexTask` to execute and then return a new value for `messages`, I need to update `messages` in sync with `complexTask` (i.e - as soon as `complexTask` updates `messages`, the change should be reflected on my website).

However, doing the above requires accessing `vm` from within `complexTask` which is impossible unless I attach `vm` to the browser's `window` object.

What is the proper way to let `complexTask` update the `messages` list?

Comment: its time to lift your state up with something like : `vuex`, `redux`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how `complexTask` changes `messages`.

If it *replaces* messages -> just return new messages and update Vue component data:

```js
    buttonClicked: function() {
        this.complexTaskInProgress = true 
        //A method imported from another file 
        this.messages = await complexTask()
        complexTaskInProgress = false 
    }
```

If it *modifies* messages (adds, updates, removes objects), just current messages inside the function and return **new** array of updated messages:

```js
    buttonClicked: function() {
        this.complexTaskInProgress = true 
        // `complexTask` copies original array of messages and return it with all require modifications
        this.messages = await complexTask(this.messages);
        complexTaskInProgress = false 
    }
```

Btw, this can be solved by custom Vuex plugin

---

**Using state manager (Vuex/Redux/etc).** In this case you will have one single state tree for whole application (single source of truth). For example, you can write custom Vuex plugin to fix this issue. It has access to current state and can run mutations/actions when needed. Read more about this [here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/plugins.html)

---

**Using shared state**. In this case you will pass around only shared state instead of whole component instance so overhead if much lower. Also it's simplier you implement than using state manager. [Read more about this here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch)

Comment: I'm afraid I wasn't very clear. I need to continuously update `messages`. I updated my post with an example.

Comment: It seems like you need state manager then. Custom vuex plugins can access state at any time and call actions/mutations when needed

Comment: @Roymunson Update. Added info about state manager and shared state